# JavaScript: Sorting the columns in a 2D array by the values in a row

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this:

```
 [[ 'Table', 'Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C'],
  [ 'Row 1', 10, 5, 7 ],
  [ 'Row 2', 20, 15, 50 ],
  [ 'Row 3', 8, 13, 3 ]]
```

I would like to sort the columns, so the 'most important' column shows first, by sorting on the data in 'Row 1'. Result:

```
 [[ 'Table', 'Column A', 'Column C', 'Column B'],
 [ 'Row 1', 10, 7, 5 ],
 [ 'Row 2', 20, 50, 12 ],
 [ 'Row 3', 8, 3, 13 ]]
```

Notice how column C and B has changed position.

How can I do this in JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this :

```
var test = [[ 'Table', 'Column A', 'Column C', 'Column B'],
         [ 'Row 1', 10, 7, 5 ],
         [ 'Row 2', 20, 50, 12 ],
         [ 'Row 3', 8, 3, 13 ]];


function arrayColReorder(array, col1, col2) {
    for (var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        var temp=array[i][col1];
        array[i][col1]=array[i][col2];
        array[i][col2]=temp;
    }
    return array;
}

var sorted = arrayColReorder(test, 2, 3);

console.log(sorted);
```

[image]